# add new array if array's specified sub array's value is not the same

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array, laravel-5

First I have this array

```
$age = $request->age //laravel's input

$m_array = array(
   'jason' => array(
      'age' => '21', 
      'gender' => 'male'
     ),
   'mechelle' => array(
      'age' => '19', 
      'gender' => 'female'
     ),
   'Khent' => array(
      'age' => '25', 
      'gender' => 'male'
     )
  );
```

and then check if a specified array exist from the $m_array arrays

```
if(isset($m_array['jason'])):

endif
```

and then I want to check if each array that has a 'jason' value and its sub array named 'age' has the same value from the variable '$age' and if does not then add the same array but not the same sub array named 'age' value e.g.

```
$m_array['jason'] = array('age' => $age, 'gender' => 'male')
```

so the expected output if an array is added with the same name but not the same sub array named 'age' value will be

```
$m_array = array(
    'jason' => array(
       'age' => '21', 
       'gender' => male
      ),
    'jason' => array(
        'age' => '18', 
        'gender' => male
     )
  );
```

any ideas, help, clues, recommendations, suggestions to achieve that please?

Comment: You can use `in_array()` and `array_column()` to check if the age value of the new array is already in your array age column. If not add it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just check the `$m_array['jason']` exists or not, if not then the add a new array into the main array.

Try adding `'jason' => array('age' => '21', 'gender' => 'male'),` in the main array, you will get a message `Already exist` and if you run this you will be notified `Array Inserted`.

> As per your last requirement I also check for that array has the same
>   sub array or not, if not then add the array into the main array.

```
$age = '22';
$gender = 'male';
$m_array = array('jason' => array('age' => '21', 'gender' => 'male'),
                 'mechelle' => array('age' => '19', 'gender' => 'female'),
                 'Khent' => array('age' => '25', 'gender' => 'male')
                );

if(isset($m_array['jason']) && is_array($m_array['jason'])){
    if($m_array['jason']['age'] == $age && $m_array['jason']['gender'] == $gender)
        echo 'Already exist';
    else
        $m_array['jason'] = array('age' => $age, 'gender' => $gender);
}else{
    $m_array['jason'] = array('age' => $age, 'gender' => $gender);
    echo 'Array Inserted';
}

print_r($m_array);
```

**Result:**

The value `age` overridden.

```
Array
(
    [jason] => Array
        (
            [age] => 22
            [gender] => male
        )

    [mechelle] => Array
        (
            [age] => 19
            [gender] => female
        )

    [Khent] => Array
        (
            [age] => 25
            [gender] => male
        )

)
```

> Note: The same key of an array never added, its must be override, So you 
>   will loss data. Don't do that, This is what you want. But this is not
>   possible.

Comment: assume there's multiple array keys named 'jason' would that check each sub array named 'age' that has a parent key named 'jason;?

Comment: @CodeDemon, You wanted it, Why you tested the Programmer?? As you want to add the same key twice i just give you the way how could you do that thing and also add a `Note` as warning.